# How to build a shortest spanning trees that respects existing connections using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, network, shortest-path

I have

a) a point layer of connection points to an existing network, i.e. an existing network can be accessed here.

b) a point layer of sites that should be connected newly to the existing network

I want to generate the shortest spanning trees to connect the point of layer b) to any of the points of layer a).

With the [ReconstructLine](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/reconstruct_line/) plugin I can build the shortest spanning tree between all point of both layers, but this tree is more than I need as it builds a new network between every points. I would need a spanning tree plugin that respects the already existing connections between the points of layer b.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the second variation of Minimum Spanning Tree plugin on Qgis if you have edges as shapefile 
NOT: you should read the description of the update